# Is this proof right for The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra with matrix theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, roots

$\forall f(x) = \sum _{i = 0} ^{n} a_i x^i, (n \ge 1, a_i \in \mathbb C)$ Let $g(x) = \dfrac {1} {a_n} f(x),$ then: 
$g(\lambda) = \left \vert \lambda I - A \right \vert $ ($A$ is a  [Frobenius companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix))

$= \left \vert \lambda I - P^{-1}JP \right \vert $ ( $J$ is a [Jordan matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix))

$=  \vert P^{-1} \vert \left \vert \lambda I - J \right \vert \vert P \vert $
$=  \left \vert \lambda I - J \right \vert $
$= \prod _{i = 1} ^{n} (\lambda - \lambda_i )$

$\Rightarrow f(\lambda) = a_n g(\lambda) = a_n \prod _{i = 1} ^{n} (\lambda - \lambda_i )$

Comment: existance of Jordan matrix assumes the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: This proof is fine if you can show the existence of the Jordan decomposition without using the fundamental theorem of algebra. In fact, this is equivalent with the theorem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you prove the existence of the Jordan normal form without assuming the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra?